# mosquitto.db file does not get created

Tags: persistence, mqtt, mosquitto

In the process of testing mosquitto Persistence, I have removed mosquitto.db from Persistence location to enable a fresh start. But, to my chagrin, the file does not get created even after I restart the broker.

Did I get it wrong that the broker creates the .db file as per the config? Any pointers on how to get a fresh mosquitto.db file would be appreciated.

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
max_inflight_messages 1

persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
allow_anonymous false
max_queued_messages 1000000

autosave_interval 30
# autosave_on_changes false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the file while the broker is running it is likely to not get recreated because the broker will already hold an open file handle.

Deleting a file while it's open by a process does not actually remove the file, just it's entry in the directory, the process will continue to read/write to the file until the handle is closed.

If you  restart mosquitto after deleting the file it won't write to the file until it actually has some data to write to it, e.g.

- have a subscribed client (at QOS 1 or 2)
- send some messages
- disconnect the subscriber
- send more messages
- shutdown mosquitto

The file should now be written containing the messages that were published while the client was disconnected.

Comment: Many Thanks for the prompt reply. When I tried the above and checked the mosquitto logs, it says access denied for writing to the .db file. I guess that's where the issue lies.

Comment: How did you restart the broker? Because if it was running before and writing to the location in the config it should have been able to write the new file when it needed to

Comment: We did it with the usual way: sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf & using the same config file. What we messed though was while deleting the file, we deleted the parent directories and recreated them. So, what permissions it had earlier were lost. Gave it the needed permissions now and it's writing away now like it has never stopped.. :) Bliss! Thanks for all the help!